# Javascript : dropping specific objects only in specific places

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have several draggable objects and several places where it is possible to drop an object. But I don't want anything to be dropped anywhere. Let's say object A should only be dropped in place 1 and object B should only be dropped in place 2.

I discovered that fiddling with "function drop(event)" was not a good idea. If Firefox couldn't drop, it tried to redirect instead and to go to a site name-of-my-object.com.

Setting .ondragover to "return false;", even under specific conditions (ie. wrong object for this place) made the place undroppable for all objects.

Using

```
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
```

to get the place to accept objects again was indiscriminate : every place accepted any object.

I've been fighting this for more than a day and, try as I might, I couldn't find a functioning example anywhere online.

Answer (score 0):

The function to interfere with was the "function allowDrop(event)".

Complete functioning example :

```js
var draggedObject = "";
var sentence = "";
var rectangle = "";
var canDrop = true;

function dragStart(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
  draggedObject = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = draggedObject + " is moving<br>";
}

function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (event.dataTransfer.getData("text") == "drag1") {
    sentence = "<br>" + draggedObject + " is OVER ";
  }
  if (event.dataTransfer.getData("text") == "drag2") {
    sentence = "<br>" + draggedObject + " is OVER ";
  }

  rectangle = event.target.id;
  if (rectangle == 'droptarget2') {
    document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = sentence + "droptarget2";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = sentence + "droptarget1";
  }
  if ((rectangle == 'droptarget2') && (draggedObject == 'drag1')) canDrop = false;
  if ((rectangle == 'droptarget1') && (draggedObject == 'drag2')) canDrop = false;
  if ((rectangle == 'droptarget1') && (draggedObject == 'drag1')) canDrop = true;
  if ((rectangle == 'droptarget2') && (draggedObject == 'drag2')) canDrop = true;
}


function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (canDrop == false) return;
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = draggedObject + " was dropped.";
}
```

```css
.droptarget1 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.droptarget2 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  background: pink;
}

.drag1 {
  color: green;
}

.drag2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h3>
        Drag and drop possibilities : </h3>
      <p>The green "Drag1" text can only be dropped into the green rectangle. The red "Drag2" text can only be dropped into the pink rectangle.
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="drag1" name="drag1" class="drag1">Drag1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="drag2" name="drag2" class="drag2">Drag2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="droptarget1" class="droptarget1" name="droptarget1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="droptarget2" class="droptarget2" name="droptarget2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="textHere"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet.